# Translating Equations to Algorithms

Tags: functions, bezier-curve

I can't understand equations. But I'm a software engineer. I think the brevity of the equation is confusing to me where a program spells it all out.

Trying to translate the equation for a bezier curve into javascript. The equation on wikipedia appears as-

[image]

Translating this to javascript looks like this-

```
function B(t, p0, p1, p2, p3) {
  return Math.pow((1 - t), 3) * p0 + 3 * Math.pow((1 - t), 2) * p1 + 3 * (1 - t) * Math.pow(t, 2) * p2 + Math.pow(t, 3) * p3;
}
```

But this doesn't make sense. A point is made up of an x and y coordinate. How can multiple values be represented by a single value in a meaningful way? How is this equation usable?

Comment: Are not the $\mathbf{P}_i$ vectors, i.e. ordered pairs of coordinates?

Comment: Maybe. But how would you write that? For the first operation do you multiply `Math.pow((1 - t), 3)` by P0.x and P0.y?

Comment: The equation as stated is actually two equations, one for the x-component and one for the y-component. All the same operations are done in each, just on different components of each vector. You might find it easier to work with each component separately, or set up something to do both, although I don't know how the mechanics of javascript will do that.

Comment: Back on this trying to figure it out. I must have written func B wrong?

http://jsbin.com/reyebokoqe/edit?html,console,output

Comment: Updated version-

http://jsbin.com/vedicediko/1/edit?html,console,output

Comment: At this point I got it working by copying javascript I've found. But I'm trying to figure out why **I** wasn't able to do it. I've got to do Linear, Quadratic, Cubic, Quartic, and Quintic functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned, the "$\mathbf{P}$" things are 2D points; each of them has an $x$ coordinate and a $y$ coordinate. Or, actually, in some situations, the $\mathbf{P}$ objects might be 3D points having $x$ , $y$ and $z$ coordinates.

So, suppose $\mathbf{P}_0$ has coordinates $(x_0,y_0)$, and, similarly, $\mathbf{P}_1 = (x_1,y_1)$, $\mathbf{P}_2 = (x_2,y_2)$, and $\mathbf{P}_3 = (x_3,y_3)$. Then the necessary code is:

```
s = 1-t
f0 = s*s*s
f1 = 3*s*s*t
f2 = 3*s*t*t
f3 = t*t*t

x = f0*x0 + f1*x1 + f2*x2 + f3*x3
y = f0*y0 + f1*y1 + f2*y2 + f3*y3
```

There are ways to write this that involve slightly fewer arithmetic operations, but I thought clarity would be more important than performance, at this stage.

I don't know much about Javascript, but in other languages (C# for example) you would create a Point class and you would overload the "+" and "*" operators. Then you woud be able to write code that looks exactly like the formula you cited:

```
p = f0*p0 + f1*p1 + f2*p2 + f3*p3
```

Here `f0*p0` represents the number `f0` multiplied by the point `p0`, and so on.

Comment: Thanks. Others comments as well as your answer definitely points me in the right direction.